# Is there a way to select a number of random values of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe called df whose dimension is 123x100, 123 rows and 100 columns, so in total there is 12300 values (not neccesarily different)

I want to assign a 1/10 of them the value "0", but I don't know how to select them randomly

The closest thing I've reached is selecting 12 random rows and 10 random columns and then replace the values in the intersection, but I dont want it like this because I would like the selected random values not to be in the same columns/rows.

Comment: Do you want exactly 1/10th? Or about 1/10th?

Comment: How are the source data distributed, randomly?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: what if we can manage to create a 1-dimentional view into values, e.g. `df.values` or `df.to_numpy(copy=False)`:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng; rng = default_rng(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((10,10)), dtype=int)

mask = rng.choice(range(df.size), size=df.size//10, replace=False)
df.values.ravel()[mask] = 0
```

Comment: Nice use of the underlying array ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace ~10%:

```
import numpy as np

df[np.random.random(size=df.shape)<1/10] = 0

# check how many values were replaced
df.size - df.sum().sum()
# 1244
```

For exactly 10% (rounded to a valid integer):

```
a = np.arange(df.size)
np.random.shuffle(a)

df[a.reshape(df.shape) < df.size/10] = 0

# check
df.size - df.sum().sum()
# 1230
```